# c++ character comparison between a number char and a letter char

Tags: c++, string, comparison, char

I have a string variable named tablolar and in this case it's value is "tablo2" and according to my intension it can not enter in if statement but it enters and i couldn't find out why.

```
for(int z=0;z<tablolar.size();){
    if((tablolar[z]==',')||(tablolar[z]=='a')||(tablolar[z]=='b')
     ||(tablolar[z]=='c')||(tablolar[z]=='d')||(tablolar[z]=='e')
     ||(tablolar[z]=='f')||(tablolar[z]=='g')||(tablolar[z]=='h')
     ||(tablolar[z]=='i')||(tablolar[z]=='j')||(tablolar[z]=='k')
     ||(tablolar[z]=='l')||(tablolar[z]=='m')||(tablolar[z]=='n')
     ||(tablolar[z]=='o')||(tablolar[z]=='p')||(tablolar[z]=='q')
     ||(tablolar[z]=='r')||(tablolar[z]=='s')||(tablolar[z]=='t')
     ||(tablolar[z]=='u')||(tablolar[z]=='v')||(tablolar[z]=='w')
     ||(tablolar[z]=='x')||(tablolar[z]=='y')||(tablolar[z]=='z')) {
    //enters here but it must not enter
}
```

Comment: It should enter. Check your code once more. What do you expect when tablolar[z] = 't'

Comment: did you forget `z++`?

Answer (score 4):

Your check includes checking that the current symbol is `'t'`, and if the string is `'tablo2'`, it's first character is `'t'`.

By the way, this check could be done much simplier:

```
if ((tablolar[z] == ',') || (tablolar[z] >= 'a' && tablolar[z] <= 'z'))
    // do your work
```

Comment: i want to do my work if chars of the string variable tablolar does not contain any char but small letters between a-z and ','. what do you suggest?

Comment: If I understood you right, you should make this check for every char in the string, and if all of them are ',' or 'a'..'z', do your work.

Comment: if string tablolar is;
"tablo"->it is ok
"tablo,tablobir,tabloiki,tablouc"->it is ok
"ta"->it is ok
but if it is;
"tablo2"->not ok
"ta546465"->not ok
"Tablo"->not ok
"tablo,234,tablobir"->not ok
"tablo^%&!)=(,tablouc"-> not ok